# Self-contained or versionable messages?

Tags: nservicebus, messaging

I'm having some message design head-aches. I want to start up an NServiceBus saga for a long running process. Part of the data needed to do the initialization is a list of constraints, which are implementations of an abstract base class. As I've understood the design philosophy, messages should ideally be

1. Self-contained, that is contain all the data needed to process them. Following this, I would pass along all the list of constraints in the message.
2. Versionable. NServiceBus does this by using an XML serializer which does not pass along type information (see [this thread answer by Udi](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/6575)). In my case, that means I cannot on the recieving end pick up the specifics of the constraints.

The serialization problems can be "solved" by using the `BinarySerializer`, but this does not seem to be a recommended practice since it breaks versioning. The alternative is to send along some identifier so that the constraints can be retrieved from some datastore, but that would remove the "self-containedness".

Is there a third way here, or do I simply have to choose some "least bad" solution?

Comment: How is the list of constraints derived? Presumably there is some data which dictates which constraints are needed. Perhaps you should pass that data in the message, and construct the list of constraints on the consumer side?

Comment: @MattDavey: They are not data derived as such, they are configured by the user beforehand. The user can select some set of constraints that matches their business need (such as "Apply this process to users with order history > x $" or "Apply this process to users logging in between 0800 and 1000 on saturdays"). It's not straightforward (or possible, maybe) to create the list from the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of having these objects injected into your saga via DI.

Just create a boostrapping class that at startup will call:

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<yourSaga>(s => s.SomeProperty = value);
```

Comment: Will this work/is this recommended to use even if it would require a database call to populate the property?